# capture#1-of ? super C interpreted as C in generic interface

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-programming, bounded-wildcard

Given the following classes:

```
class A { public A a() {return new A();}; };
class B extends A { public B b() {return new B();} };
class C extends B { public C c() {return new C();} };
class D extends C { public D d() {return new D();} };
```

I want to write some `UnaryOperator`s that can accept instances of A, B and C, but not D.

So my choice for declaring the reference type is `UnaryOperator<? super C>`. Since I'm using `super`, it means it can also accept an instance of `Object`.

```
UnaryOperator<? super C> op1 = arg -> arg.a(); // does not compile, arg could be Object
UnaryOperator<? super C> op2 = arg -> arg.b(); // does not compile, arg could be Object
UnaryOperator<? super C> op3 = arg -> arg.c(); // does compile
UnaryOperator<? super C> op4 = arg -> arg.d(); // this is not expected to compile
```

Why does `op1` makes the code fail to compile with a message

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from A to C`

and `op2` makes the code fail to compile with a message

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from B to C`,

but `op3` compiles fine, and let me call a method available only in C?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Not accepting instances of D is a violation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: `op1 = (A arg) -> arg.a(); op2 = (B arg) -> arg.b() ...`

Comment: This is just for understanding better how the java compiler infers types in lambda expressions involving generics. You're right about the substitution principle.

It's just because, as far as I know, this behaviour is and edge case, and I want to know if there is some justification for this behaviour.

Comment: The problem you have is that both D is a C, but A is an Object, you can't defined a range in the hierarchy for the compiler to check, you would need to add a run time check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `op1` makes the code fail to compile...?

When a generic functional interface is parameterized by wildcards, there are different instantiations that could satisfy the wildcard and produce different function types. For example, each of <sup>1</sup>:

```
UnaryOperator<C> (function type C -> C);
UnaryOperator<B> (function type B -> B);
UnaryOperator<A> (function type A -> A);
UnaryOperator<Object> (function type Object -> Object);
```

is a `UnaryOperator<? super C>`.

Sometimes, it's possible to known from the context, such as the parameter types of a lambda, which function type is intended. Other times, it is necessary to pick one:

```
UnaryOperator<? super C> op1 = (A arg) -> arg.a();
                                ^

UnaryOperator<? super C> op2 = (B arg) -> arg.b();
                                ^
...
```

If you don't pick one, the bounds are used <sup>2</sup>:

```
UnaryOperator<? super C> op = arg -> arg.c(); // valid
```

Where `C` is a bound, so the lambda expression is a `UnaryOperator<C>` in this case.

---

<sup>1 - [JLS 9.9. Function Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9) - the last paragraph.
2 - [JLS 15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) - if `T` is a wildcard-parameterized functional interface type and the lambda expression is implicitly typed, then the ground target type is the non-wildcard parameterization `T`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

@Oleksandr has told you why it fails to compile. I will tell you why you cannot use `UnaryOperator<? super C>` to only accept `A, B, C` but reject `D`.

---

`UnaryOperator<? super C>` does not means the function accept `? super C`. 
It means the generic `T` in `UnaryOperator<T>` is `? super C`.

Consider you have a instance `UnaryOperator<? super C> uo`.

- Does `uo.apply(new A())` make sense? NO, because `UnaryOperator<B>` is assignable to `UnaryOperator<? super C>` but can't accept `A`.
- Does `uo.apply(new B())` make sense? NO, because `UnaryOperator<C>` is assignable to `UnaryOperator<? super C>` but can't accept `B`.

So what does `uo` can accept? The answer is `C`, because only `C` can assignable to any `? super C`.

So your `UnaryOperator<? super C>` is in fact same as `UnaryOperator<C>`. Though your IDE may tell you it accept `Object`, but it will not accept object not assignable to `C`.